# Why XML namespace is not unwanted in this XML SOAP request?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation

I don't understand why the following XML (built from a WSDL request) is invalid:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"> 
   <soap:Header /> 
   <soap:Body xmlns:m="https://test.com/schemas/Plat/"> 
         <m:TestRequest> 
                <m:transactId>TRANS_46151</m:transactId> 
                <m:param1>paramvalue1</m:param1>
         </m:TestRequest> 
   </soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

And why it becomes valid once the "m" namespace is removed from the "TestRequest" parameters, as below:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"> 
   <soap:Header /> 
   <soap:Body xmlns:m="https://test.com/schemas/Plat/"> 
         <m:TestRequest> 
                <transactId>TRANS_46151</transactId> 
                <param1>paramvalue1</param1>
         </m:TestRequest> 
   </soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

Notice: the XSD is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="https://test.com/schemas/Plat/"

    <xsd:complexType name="EnteteMessageType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="transactId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element name="param1" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="TestRequest" type="EnteteMessageType" />
</xsd:schema>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you haven't specified the element form as "[qualified](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-0-20041028/#QualLocals)":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="https://test.com/schemas/Plat/"
    xmlns:tns="https://test.com/schemas/Plat/">

    <xsd:complexType name="EnteteMessageType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="transactId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xsd:element name="param1" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="TestRequest" type="tns:EnteteMessageType" />
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: That's right! Thank you. I was confused because the XSD from http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema is using qualified attribute and element form, but this is not the case by default.